# The values of both the variables are same but still the True block doesn't get executed?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
for row in range(1, 100):
        #print(ws["C"+ str(row)].value)
        if ws["C"+ str(row)].value == entered_username:
            if ws["D"+ str(row)] == entered_password:
                dashboard()
            else:
                Label(l_screen,text="Incorrect password!!").pack(pady = 10) 
        else:
            Label(l_screen,text="Username not found.").pack(pady = 10)
```

When checking the `ws["C"+ str(row)].value` and `entered_username` separately, both are same(checked the type function as well). but the code block always returns "Username not found"

Comment: Maybe check if the types are the same? You can use `print(type(entered_username))` and `print(type(ws["C"+ str(row)].value))`.

Comment: never show what is incorrect (username or password), just mention that the combo is not found. Otherwise you can probe until you find an accepted username.

Comment: what is the type of the values?

Comment: @AnnZen Yes. I did checked that. Both are strings.

Comment: what if you looked with a debugger

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is actually a "How do I debug" question. The simplest strategy is just sprinkling everything with prints, like this (you can also use walrus in Python 3.8 and up to make it prettier):

```py
for row in range(1, 100):
        #print(ws["C"+ str(row)].value)
        if (username := ws["C"+ str(row)].value) == entered_username:
            print("Username: ", username) # <- First debug print
            password = ws["D" + str(row)]
            print("Stored password (part): ", password[0:4], "Entered password part: ", entered_password[0:4]) # <- Second debug print
            print("Passwords match :", password == entered_password) # <- third debug print
            if password == entered_password:
                dashboard()
            else:
                Label(l_screen,text="Incorrect password!!").pack(pady = 10) 
        else:
            Label(l_screen,text="Username not found.").pack(pady = 10)
```

It would be unwise to print entire passwords, so we just print first three letters to compare them. If you use breakpoints in Pycharm, for example, you can compare the passwords while developing.